# Superscrollorama + responsive design = does not flow correctly

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

Using Superscrollorama to animate in arrows on this particular site: http://itsuptous.org/new_site

It's a responsive design too. 960+, 768, 480, and 320. Using media queries to trigger the different layouts. If I load the site at any browser size the arrows animate correctly, it's when I expand or minimize the window it moves to the incorrect position. Not sure what is going on here. Does anyone have any thoughts?

I have the elements absolutely positioned to prevent horizontal scroll bars.

jQuery Superscrollorama code to follow:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //ACTIVATE BUTTON FOR SMOOTH SCROLLING
        jQuery("#scroll_button").scrollTo('#section_two_outer');

        //MOVE ARROWS ON SCROLL
        var controller = jQuery.superscrollorama();
        //INDIVIDUAL ELEMENT TWEEN
        controller.addTween('.apply_now_arrow_left', TweenMax.from(jQuery('.apply_now_arrow_left'), .5, {css:{left:'-2500px'}}));
        controller.addTween('.apply_now_button', TweenMax.from(jQuery('.apply_now_button'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
        controller.addTween('.apply_now_arrow_right', TweenMax.from(jQuery('.apply_now_arrow_right'), .5, {css:{left:'5000px'}}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Dave,

It doesn't actually look (to me) that your site has an issue with Superscrollerama, it looks like the issue you're seeing is due to the change in the inline CSS that it does to your page element.  For instance, when the animation is fired, it's just animating the CSS 'left' attribute over time, but once it's done the left attribute remains on the element which breaks your layout as the window is resized.

To fix this, I'd suggest simply using a jQuery callback after the animation completes to remove the inline CSS from the arrows, which lets your stylesheet subsequently govern their position when resizing the window.  The worst case scenario for this would then make a nearly imperceivable flicker if the animation was happening while the viewport size was changing (which I'm not even sure how to accomplish that), so I think you'd be good to go.

```
// Demo code from http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/
controller.addTween('#fade', 
  TweenMax.from($('#fade'),.5,{
    css:{opacity:0}, 
    onComplete: function(){alert('test')}
  }));
```

So, you would probably want to do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //ACTIVATE BUTTON FOR SMOOTH SCROLLING
    jQuery("#scroll_button").scrollTo('#section_two_outer');

    //MOVE ARROWS ON SCROLL
    var controller = jQuery.superscrollorama();
    //INDIVIDUAL ELEMENT TWEEN
    controller.addTween('.apply_now_arrow_left', TweenMax.from(jQuery('.apply_now_arrow_left'), .5, {css:{left:'-2500px'}, onComplete:function(){jQuery('.apply_now_arrow_left').css("left","auto")}}));
    controller.addTween('.apply_now_button', TweenMax.from(jQuery('.apply_now_button'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
    controller.addTween('.apply_now_arrow_right', TweenMax.from(jQuery('.apply_now_arrow_right'), .5, {css:{left:'5000px'}, onComplete:function(){jQuery('.apply_now_arrow_right').css("left","auto")}}));
```

Of course, YMMV depending on how your stylesheet works, so you might do something different, but that's the basic overall approach.